# Select one IdP by SP (Shibboleth)

Tags: shibboleth, service-provider

I am running a Shibboleth protected website. So in this scenario I am the service provider (SP). I connect with one federation which redirects users to different identity providers (IdP).

Is there a method/setting (at the SP-side) which can pre-select one IdP to redirect to?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your shibboleth2.xml file set your `<SSO>` element as such:

```
<SSO entityID="https://idp.example.org/idp/shibboleth">
   SAML2 SAML1
</SSO>
```

where `https://idp.example.org/idp/shibboleth` is the EntityID of the IDP that you want to allow.